# python: can't open file '.manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django

Im learning django and i get this error:

```
python: can't open file '.manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

when running

```
python .\manage.py makemigrations
```

I know im running the command in the same folder as my manage.py file, so what can be the issue?

This is my directory tree:

```
.
├── api
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
└── music_controller
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Here is the pwd where i run above command:

```
(djangotut) ether@ether:~/Documents/django-react-tutorial/music_controller$
```

Comment: You use a backslash in path. On non-Windows you must use the forward slash.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use a backslash in the path.
The correct command would be: `python manage.py makemigrations`

Naturally you will be using this in the directory where manage.py resides.

Answer (score 0):

Today I've faced this issue while doing my django project and stuck for more than 2 hours nd this one helped me.

1. first the error is manage.py file is not detected
2. so in your project folder check for manage.py file
3. if you find out manage.py file then check at which folder the manage.py file is present then note that folder name.
4. then go to terminal first check your directory then type cd space folder name
5. then type this command python manage.py runserver